# How to Enable Browser Caching on a per folder basis

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

Browser caching is extremely important, or so I've read and I figured the best way to do so with my website is by specifying the default cache duration per folder because I know about how often I update files in specific folders. However, my current htaccess file causes a 500 internal server error...

```
# Turn off the Last Modified header except for html docs
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
Header unset Last-Modified

# Turn off the ETags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minute"

  <Directory "/include">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/images">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/fonts">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/steamauth">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
  </Directory>

  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Did I mess something up in the file or am I doing this completely incorrectly?

Comment: Did you send the `.htaccess` file in text mode ?

Comment: @Croises No, because I know the .htaccess file works because I used it to set a custom 404 error page. There is something wrong with that code because once I removed it I stopped getting the 500 error.

Comment: Check the apache error_log file, it should tell you what it doesn't like

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but I found it searching for same answer. In case someone has similar problem, I did this: I created a new `.htaccess` files for specific folders, and modified times inside them for that folders. Working great for my case.